# self.tabBarController.selectedIndex not calling viewDidAppear

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidload

I've been looking at and trying all the solutions others have posted to this problem, but I'm still not getting it.

My use case is very simple. I have a viewController with a button, when that button is pressed I want to navigate to another tab and reload the data including an api call.

When using the button, I navigate to the tab fine, but viewDidAppear is not being called.

If on another tab, and navigate using the tab bar, viewDidAppear works fine. Also viewWillAppear is working, but I have to add a manual delay to the functions I want to call so it's not ideal.

So what do I need to do to navigate using self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0  and get the functionality of viewDidAppear?

**Update:** The viewWillAppear method I added gets called but I have to add a delay to my functions in order for them to work, and it's a bit clunky, not ideal. Not sure why viewDidAppear will not work :(

Here is a screenshot of the structure:
[image]

I appreciate any help on this one!

The "current" ViewController is my tab index 2:

```
import UIKit

class PostPreviewVC: UIViewController {

//Here I create a post object and post it to the timeline with the below button

    @IBAction func postButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    //create the post via Firebase api

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

    }
}
```

In my destination viewController:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SDWebImage
import AVFoundation

class HomeVC: UIViewController {

// MARK: - PROPERTIES

var posts = [Post]()
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
//more properties...


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupUI()
    configureTableView()
    reloadTimeline()

    UserFirebase.timeline { (posts) in
        self.posts = posts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    print("viewDidAppear")

    _ = self.view
    setupUI()
    configureTableView()
    reloadTimeline()

    UserFirebase.timeline { (posts) in
        self.posts = posts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    print("viewWillAppear")

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.reloadTimeline()
        self.configureTableView()
    }
}

//All the tableview code below here...
}
```

Added a custom class for my tab bar controller:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    print("viewDidAppear in tabBar custom Class called")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    print("viewWillAppear in tabBar custom Class called")
}
}
```

Comment: have you checked if tabBarController is nil or not??

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I just checked and it is not nil

Comment: can you share more code on it or just structure of your navigation.

Comment: try checking it in view will appear method of view controller life cycle.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger good thinking, I added a viewWillAppear method and it does get called, but viewDidAppear does not... any idea why this would be?

Comment: if you see view controller's lifecycle view will appear comes before view did appear. I feel there is something broken in navigation. sometime your animations and all don't work on view did appear.

Comment: I just added a snapshot of the structure, each tab is it's own storyboard, does that affect things?

Comment: In your tab bar controller, add this method viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) and call its superclass method and try checking  then your view did appear work,

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I'm a little embarrassed to ask, but where would I do that? Do I need to create a custom class for my tab bar controller? Or would I modify the UITabBarController.h file? I'm afraid to stray from swift and break everything lol

Comment: you need to add a custom class for UITabbarController. Updated it as my answer. you can go with the viewWillAppear  method to check viewcontroller is switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `UITabBarController` `viewDidLoad` only gets called once. and your `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` get called multiple times. you can either check if your `viewWillAppear` gets called or not. because your view will appear gets called before your `viewDidAppear` it's just like going through the reverse engineering process.

You can also add `viewDidAppear` method into your `UITabBarController` custom class. and call its superclass method into it in that way I think it will solve your problem.

> Note: In the case of `UITabbarController`, Always do your UI update task and API calling a task in either
>   `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I just updated my post, I added custom class for my tab bar controller... viewWillAppear is being called, but I think it's too early so the code does not execute. I thought that would happen, that's why I wanted it in viewDidAppear. That method does not get called.. I'm stumped as to why

Comment: it seems like it should b/c I'm able to print to the console, but the functions I'm calling are not being executed. I think it has to do with timing, so I'm debugging now to see where it breaks. But I still don't understand why viewDidAppear is not working.

Comment: Update: So i added a slight delay to my viewWillAppear calls and they all work. It's not an ideal solution so I'm still going to work on finding out why viewDidAppear is not being called.

Comment: I ended up removing my storyboard references and re-connecting them to get back the viewDidAppear method... not sure what broke or where, but your answer and comments helped a ton to debug. thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

When you are using `UITabBarController`, the method `viewDidLoad` will called only once when any `UIViewController` is loaded in memory. After that, when you are navigating the same `UIViewController`, then it will load from memory.

In order to overcome this problem, you must divide your code in `viewDidLoad` & `viewDidAppear`. So, in `viewDidLoad`, you only put that code which you want to intialize once throughout the app such as adding `UIView`'s or other things, while in `viewDidAppear` / `viewWillAppear`, you can make API calls or some functions which fetches dynamic data.

Finally, when you are calling `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0`, it will call `viewDidLoad` only once and `viewDidAppear` / `viewWillAppear` every time when you are navigating that `UIViewController`.

Hope this helps to understand like how `UITabBarController` works.

Comment: This is great, thanks for taking the time. I had a typo in the question, I meant to ask how to get viewDidAppear to work... In the code I posted I have my viewDidAppear code, but it's not being called when I use self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0. Is there anything else I need to make that work? Some solutions talk about a subclass for UITabBarController, but I haven't had luck with those either.

Comment: @TJMac Can you pls put some code like from where you are calling this?

Comment: Ok I just updated with more code to show context. My HomeVC has  a lot of code so I simplified to keep it clean. let me know if there is more to consider than what I've added. Thanks again!